# Value Conversion issue: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gpuimage, ios7.1

I just updated my Xcode's version to 5.1 and this error occurred. I'm using the GPUImage library. Here's a screenshot. Thanks in advance guys![image: error screenshot]

Comment: Maybe NSInteger rather than integer?

Comment: Please put your code here rather than screenshot. It will help us to solve.

Comment: You must be working off of some really old code, because those lines  of code in the framework were updated back in September to prevent this. You might want to update to a more modern version from the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 14):

`size_t` (size type) is an integral type for the size of objects (C objects, not Objective-C objects) and types.  The size of `size_t` objects (the number of bits it occupies) depends on the pointer size of the used architecture. The size of `int` objects (the number of bits it occupies) is independent of that and often smaller. So potentially the assignment of a value of the type `size_t` to a variable of the type `int`can fail, if the value is that big that it fits into a `size_t` object, but not into an `int` object.

You can do one of the following:

1 Make the variables `bufferHeight` and `bufferWidth` of the type `size_t`, too.

2 Make the variables `bufferHeight` and `bufferWidth` of an integral type that is at least as big as `size_t`, i. e. `long` or `NSInteger`. (It depends on the architecture you use.)

3 The error messages warns you about the fact that the *implicit* conversion of a bigger into a smaller type will fail, if the value stores in the bigger type cannot be represented by the smaller type. If you are sure that the values (the result of the functions) always fit into an `int`, make the cast explicit.

```
int bufferHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(…);
```

BTW: Please do *not* post screenshots if the content of the screenshot is text. Copy your code and the error message instead. You can copy & paste error messages.